# Algorithm to find indices of two numbers in Series with difference within a specified range

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas

I have a list of numbers (sorted in increasing order, no repeats) and I'd like to write an algorithm that will quickly return the indices of two elements in the list whose difference is within a specified range.

This could be multiple pairs of indices, but my intention is to adjust make the range small enough to capture only one or two, then do some decisioning based off of the indices.

I'm currently using Python (a Pandas Series actually) to implement this in the following way:

- Loop through all elements in the Series
- Subtract that element from the Series
- Use a conditional statement (`np.where((list >= min) & (list < min + tol))`) that returns the indices that I'm interested in

As I'm already using Pandas vectorized operations for the subtraction and the conditional statement, I think should be a way to vectorize the loop portion as well.

Edit: Added current implementation and data sample:

```
gmin = np.inf
for t in range(run.shape[0] - 1):
    diffs =  run - run.ix[run.index[t]] + run.ix[run.index[0]]
    vals = np.where((diffs >= dis) & (diffs < dis + tol))
    if vals[0].shape[0] > 0:
        mint = np.min(vals)
        time = diffs.index[mint] - diffs.index[t]
        if time < gmin:
            gmin = time
```

and what the Pandas Series `run` looks like:

```
run.head()
Out[6]:
0.000    0.030800
1.000    0.034410
2.000    0.038020
3.001    0.041634
4.001    0.045244
Name: DISTANCE, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Show us some implementation!

Comment: How large is your data set?

Comment: @IanS The data set isn't prohibitively large (this run is only ~3k elements), but I'd like to do this for hundreds of these sets, up to ~20-30k elements in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataset is not too large, you can use numpy's `substract.outer`:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(1000)).cumsum()
diffs = np.subtract.outer(s, s)
```

This generates a matrix with all the pairwise differences from your series (you're only interested in the lower triangle really).

You can then apply `np.where` as you did to find the indices where your condition is fulfilled:

```
min = 0.1
tol = 0.05
where = np.where((diffs >= min) & (diffs < min + tol))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Just for reference:
old method: **Wall time: 2.07 s**
method from solution: **Wall time: 109 ms**